# (Помогите изменить код )Зафиксировать блок в центре страницы по вертикали при скролл

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Есть блок `.fix` , у него по умолчанию `position: relative`.
Как сделать, чтобы этот блок фиксировался, когда он будет ровно по центру экрана?

Нашел вот такую строку.

```
var topWinside=$(window).height()/2-25;
```

Как ее внедрить в мой кусок кода?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
    $('.fix').addClass('scroll');
  } else {
    $('.fix').removeClass('scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapp {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #babab;
  height: 200vh;
  display: table;
}

.dtcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 70%;
}

.dtcell:last-child {
  width: 30%;
}

.wrapper-content {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 30%;
  right: 0;
}

.wrap-img-inside {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  top: 30%;
}

.fix {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.scroll {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="dtcell">
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using
    Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default
    model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that
    it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and
    a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
    text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
    Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
    normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
    ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
  <div class="dtcell">
    <div class="wrapper-content">
      <div class="wrap-img-inside">
        <div class="fix"></div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Air, чот смешались вместе люди, кони ....

Comment: Вроде и так фиксируется...

Comment: @MedvedevDev, не понял  тебя, если честно...

Comment: @Air, я подумал, что это чей-то фиддл, а не автора вопроса, думал ты перенес в виджет код который не имеет ничего общего с кодом автора ... ну в общем не суть xDD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var $fixBlock = $('.fix');
  var $fixPlaceBlock = $fixBlock.parent('.fixPlace');
  var fixBlockHalfHeight = $fixPlaceBlock.innerHeight() / 2;

  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    $fixBlock.toggleClass('scroll', $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() / 2 - fixBlockHalfHeight >= $fixPlaceBlock.offset().top);
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapp {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #babab;
  height: 200vh;
  display: table;
}

.dtcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 70%;
}

.dtcell:last-child {
  width: 30%;
}

.wrapper-content {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 30%;
  right: 0;
}

.wrap-img-inside {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  top: 30%;
}

.fixPlace, .fix {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.fix {
  background-color: red;
}

.scroll {
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-0%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="dtcell">
    What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
    with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using
    Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default
    model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum
    is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that
    it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and
    a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
    text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
    Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
    normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem
    ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
  <div class="dtcell">
    <div class="wrapper-content">
      <div class="wrap-img-inside">
        <div class="fixPlace">
          <div class="fix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Но если развернуть на весь экран оно скачет как и в исходнике :(

Comment: @entithat, проблема в том, что вы запускаете iframe, затем изменяете его размер. А все параметры мы снимали изначально (по идее это хороший тон, что бы не пересчитывать постоянно одно и то же). Если обернуть блок - приемлемо, то можно это пофиксить ...

Comment: @entithat, добавил обертку, по идее сейчас должно быть лучше. Но такие штуки в идеале бы конечно делать по факту, что бы лишние расчеты не делать, ибо `.onscroll` и так очень много ресурсов жрет.

Comment: Жрет и не мало, но что поделаешь, если надо сделать все аккуратненько:)) Теперь бомба!)

Comment: @MedvedevDev Огромное спасибо!
Подскажите еще, а можно сделать, чтобы класс добавлялся к `body` ?

Comment: @SerhiyBilik, ну, класс `body` задается через `$('body').addClass('class')` как не странно, другое дело при каких условиях это требуется сделать )))

Comment: @MedvedevDev
я имею ввиду, вместо `div.fix` добавлять класс к `body`?

Comment: @SerhiyBilik, так то же самое, только вместо `$fixBlock.toggleClass('scroll', [расчеты]);` - `$('body').toggleClass('scroll', [расчеты]);`